# Kivy Ios ./toolchain.py build kivy not working

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, kivy, toolchain

I was following the tutorial at https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-ios.html

Got up to `./toolchain.py build kivy` and it doesnt work, this is the output

```
[DEBUG   ] error: command '/tmp/tmpZReB1k' failed with exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./toolchain.py", line 1568, in <module>
    ToolchainCL()
  File "./toolchain.py", line 1281, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.command)()
  File "./toolchain.py", line 1322, in build
    build_recipes(args.recipe, ctx)
  File "./toolchain.py", line 1158, in build_recipes
    recipe.execute()
  File "/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 729, in execute
    self.build_all()
  File "/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 84, in _cache_execution
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 837, in build_all
    self.build(arch)
  File "/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 84, in _cache_execution
    f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 811, in build
    self.build_arch(arch)
  File "/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 1112, in build_arch
    _env=build_env)
  File "/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/toolchain.py", line 67, in shprint
    for line in cmd:
  File "./tools/external/sh.py", line 565, in next
    self.wait()
  File "./tools/external/sh.py", line 500, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "./tools/external/sh.py", line 516, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc(self.ran, self.process.stdout, self.process.stderr)
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: '/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/python setup.py build_ext -g'

  STDOUT:
running build_ext
building 'ios' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7
/tmp/tmpZReB1k -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -O3 -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/include/x86_64/freetype -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/include/x86_64/ffi -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/include/x86_64/openssl -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/include/common/sdl2 -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/include/common/sdl2_image -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/include/common/sdl2_mixer -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/include/common/sdl2_ttf -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/include/x86_64 -g -I/Users/abdulgilani/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/include/python3.7m -c ios.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7... (18298 more, please see e.stdout)

  STDERR:
```

Im using python3, macOS mojave 10.14, xcode 11.0

Comment: Have you tried the instructions from the official github page for kivy-ios (https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios)? They're a bit different. Also, I have a video on YouTube about using kivy-ios if you want a video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UAi3PG-qN2k).

Comment: @Erik I have followed both tutorial and the same error shows up at the toolchain.py build kivy stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this issue and it was to switch back to XCode 10.3